# UBUNTU, NODE-GYP, CANVAS- get build error

Tags: javascript, npm, canvas, node-gyp

Hello I have problem with installation Canvas package.

Package Version 6.1.13 and tried 6.1.3

System: Ubuntu 18.04.5
Node 12.18.4 LTS
Python 2.7
g++ installed
pkg-config installed
libjpeg installed

After npm install canvas or pure install I get:

```
canvas@1.6.13 install /home/grzegorz/www/ouch/BodySpaces.Portal/node_modules/fabric/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/grzegorz/www/ouch/BodySpaces.Portal/node_modules/fabric/node_modules/canvas/build'
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
  COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
In file included from ../../../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:0,
                 from ../../../../nan/nan.h:222,
                 from ../src/Canvas.h:22,
                 from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
../../../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h: In static member function ‘static Nan::imp::ToFactoryBase<v8::Boolean>::return_t Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Boolean>::convert(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
../../../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:51: warning: ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Boolean> v8::Value::ToBoolean(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’ is deprecated (declared at /home/grzegorz/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.4/include/node/v8.h:2663): ToBoolean can never throw. Use Local version. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       val->To ## TYPE(isolate->GetCurrentContext())                            \
                                                   ^
../../../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘X’
 X(Boolean)
```

and lot more similar.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade NodeJs to v8.16.2 will solve this problem and node-gyp is not yelling anymore in logs.